# why does my fiddle look different than my page?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

Soooo... I was working on this page using jsFiddle and it doesn't work the same on the actual page!

http://jsfiddle.net/8Hpmj/8/
http://ktaadn.me/about/

The ktaadn.me example isn't left-justified and filling the width below the logo.

What did I do wrong?

If you need inspiration this is my seductive, unhelpful cat.
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NVtngGt43Rs/Tcmmw6RR-zI/AAAAAAAABOI/UPYJJHpAlk8/s640/IMG_9728.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `padding:0;` to `.nav1`
and `width:100%` to the anchor tags `odd.a and such`

that should fix it.

tip: do not use these css grid frameworks if you are not very solid at it.

good luck man.

Comment: I want to learn how to use it so I'm doing it on my own site - is it worth me wrestling with if time isn't an issue for this project? Moments earlier I figured out I wasn't using the "normalizing css" and didn't have a proper zeroing method. Thanks!

Comment: no problem. if time is not an issue, css from scratch is always better you should also use resets http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/ . you seem new to SO, you can upvote answers too. good luck

Comment: Yeah, I don't use SO much because its all above my head for the most part. People are always very helpful here. Learned a lot so far. Thanks again.